# how to catch all values of a record into a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

For a utility that I am writing I would like to collect all values of a select result (yielding a single row only!) into a string. I.e. for a statement like

```
select * from some_table where some_column = 'somevalue';
```

(where some_column is a primary key of that table, i.e. it's guaranteed to contain only unique values)

I would like to collect all values into a single string such as `'value1, value2, ... , valueN'`, i.e. essentially like the "values (...)" part of an SQL insert statement.

edit: I added a section trying to better explain where I am aiming at:

The below code snippet is what I have come up with so far. In real life the variables `p_table_name`, `p_row_name` and `p_row_value` are arguments passed into my utility. IMHO that code feels just too complicated for what it achieves. I can't help but believing that there must be an easier way to do this.

```
DECLARE
    p_table_name     VARCHAR2(30) := 'TICKET';
    p_row_name       VARCHAR2(30) := 'TICKET_ID';
    p_row_value      VARCHAR(100) := '72';
    query_statement  VARCHAR2(1000);
    column_value     VARCHAR2(1000); 
    p_all_row_values VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
BEGIN
    for curr_col in (
            select cols.column_name
            from user_tab_columns cols
            where cols.table_name = p_table_name
            order by cols.column_id
        )
    loop
        query_statement := 'select coalesce(to_char(' || curr_col.column_name || '), ''null'') from ' || p_table_name || ' where ' || p_row_name || ' = ' || p_row_value;
        execute immediate query_statement into column_value;
        p_all_row_values := p_all_row_values || ', ' || curr_col.column_name || '=' || column_value;
    end loop;
    p_all_row_values := SUBSTR(p_all_row_values,3);
    dbms_output.put_line('values are: "' || p_all_row_values || '"');
END;
```

This creates output that for a table "TICKET" and its rows reads e.g.:

```
values are: "TICKET_ID=72, TICKET_ID_VALUE=c32c717b33e543bbae4955e803624ffa, ERSTELLT_AM=15.01.20 16:51:04.817000, TICKET_VORGAENGER_ID=null, OPERATION_ID=1, QUELLSYSTEM_ID=2"
```

Note: In the example above I also added the column names plus '=' to the string but in real life I actually just want the values separated by commas as in my original question.

Hope I could make myself clear...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two *close, but not close enough* options.

The first one is to use SQL*Plus and set column separator to a comma:

```
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL>
SQL> select * from dept where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO,DNAME         ,LOC
----------,--------------,-------------
        10,ACCOUNTING    ,NEW YORK
```

The resulting line *looks like* what you want.

Another option is to concatenate columns with separators:

```
SQL> select deptno ||','|| dname ||','|| loc from dept where deptno = 10;

DEPTNO||','||DNAME||','||LOC
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10,ACCOUNTING,NEW YORK

SQL>
```

This looks even better.

However, major drawback is that you can't use it in the `VALUES` (if that's what you wanted) because - as long as it is OK for numbers, it'll fail for strings which have to be enclosed into single quotes. Not to mention dates - which format will you use? What if they contain time component (hours, minutes, ...)?

Maybe it is just me who can't do that properly, but - I'm not sure you can do that in an easy but correct manner for all datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the effort! They are indeed close but neither fits my bill. The first because I need the result in a string that I can continue to operate on in my tool. The second one because my columns are "dynamic", i.e. it should work for ALL tables, so I can't hard-code specific column names. I'll amend my question to make this clearer.